# How to fix "_this2.setState is not a function"

Tags: react-native

Error while calling API and get list than a set that lists into the list from state. but `setState()` is not work properly and warning is

> _this2.setState is not a function

```
callGithubApi(){
    axios.get("https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json")
        .then(function(response)
        {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data.movies))
            this.setState({   // problem is here
                list: response.data.movies,
                show: false
            })
        })
        .catch(error => 
        {
            this.setState({ errors : error, show: false })
        });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use ES6's arrow function:

```
callGithubApi = () => {
    axios.get("https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json")
      .then(function(response)
      {
           console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data.movies))
           this.setState({   // proble is here
           list: response.data.movies,
           show: false
         })
       })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ errors : error, show: false })
      });
  }
```

or else you have to bind this function in contructor:

```
this.callGithubApi = this.callGithubApi.bind(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ES6's arrow function for that function and the function in then()

```js
callGithubApi = () => {
    axios.get("https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json")
      .then((response) =>
      {
           console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data.movies))
           this.setState({
             list: response.data.movies,
             show: false
         })
       })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ errors : error, show: false })
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Fat arrow function to fix this context issue.

```
callGithubApi(){
   axios.get("https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json")
    .then((response) =>
    {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data.movies))
        this.setState({   // problem is here
            list: response.data.movies,
            show: false
        })
    })
    .catch(error => 
    {
        this.setState({ errors : error, show: false })
    });
 }
```